# Type mismatch when passing member function pointer to a function that takes MFP with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a template function that takes pointer to a member function of any type with any amount of arguments (but enforces some rules - it has to be void and the last argument has to be a pointer):

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    template<typename T, typename Out, typename ... In>
    void foo(T *obj, void(T::*func)(In ..., Out*)) {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

When I try to invoke the function, I get a type mismatch error:

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {}
    void bar(int in, bool *out) {
        ...
    }
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   Bar bar;

   foo.foo<Bar, bool, int>(&bar, &Bar::bar);
   ...
}
```

Error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:41:44: error: no matching function to call to 'Foo::foo(Bar*, void (Bar::*)(int, bool*))'
    foo.foo<Bar, bool, int>(&bar, &Bar::bar);
                                           ^
test.cpp:24:10: note: candidate: template<class T, class Out, class ... In> void Foo::foo(T*, void (T::*)(In ..., Out*))
    void foo(T *obj, void(T::*func)(In ..., Out*))
         ^
test.cpp:24:10: note    template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:41:44: note    mismatched types 'bool*' and 'int'
    foo.foo<Bar, bool, int>(&bar, &Bar::bar);
                                           ^
```

The interesting things is that when I make `In` a simple type instead of parameter pack then it compiles and works correctly. This seems to me like if the compiler did not expand the pack somewhere and try to match the second argument (`bool*`) to the first argument (`int`) instead of the second one.

Comment: I don't think it will help, but is there a reason you use a pointer-to-member function instead of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

Comment: VC++ 14.0 compiles it without a problem.

Comment: Doesn't the `...` have to appear last in a function parameter list?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The real code is a bit more complex, it supports both member and non-member functions, storing `std::function` for the non-member version in `Foo::mFunc` (`Foo` itself is a template class). The `Foo::foo()` method in the example above would look something like:

    `template<typename T, typename Out, typename ... In>
    void foo(T *obj, void(T::*func)(In ..., Out*)) {
        mFunc = [obj, func](In && ... in, Out *out) {
            (obj->*func)(std::forward<In>(in) ..., out);
        };
    }`

Comment: @BoPersson: I think it only has to appear last in the `template` definition, but can be used anywhere in function declaration or body, because by the time the pack is already known to compiler and can be safely expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more of messing around with compilers, I found a simple workaround in a form of a template wrapper. Apparently gcc and clang have no problem with expanding the `In ...` pack before `Out*` in a type alias (`using` or `typedef`) and only struggle when it's part of a function definition.

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, typename Out, typename ... In>
    struct funcHelper {
        using type = void(T::*)(In ..., Out*);
    };
}

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    template<typename T, typename Out, typename ... In>
    void foo(T *obj, typename detail::funcHelper<T, Out, In ...>::type func) {
        ...
    }
    ...
};



class Bar {
public:
    Bar() {}
    void bar(int in, bool *out) {
        ...
    }
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   Bar bar;

   foo.foo<Bar, bool, int>(&bar, &Bar::bar);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly why your example doesn't work, but a possible solution is to write a trait to check if the last type in a parameter pack is a pointer, then `std::enable_if` on that:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct last_is_pointer : std::false_type{};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
struct last_is_pointer<T1, T2, Ts...> : last_is_pointer<T2,Ts...>{};

template <typename T>
struct last_is_pointer<T> : std::is_pointer<T>{};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<last_is_pointer<Args...>::value>::type
    foo(T *obj, void(T::*func)(Args...)) {

    }
};
```

Then simply call this without specifying any template arguments:

```
foo.foo(&bar, &Bar::bar);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7408fe6d4b682f90)

Comment: Or use `static_assert` instead of `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @Fireho Sure, but I think type requirements belong in the declaration rather than the definition.